# How to create a CNAME Record with AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-route53

[image: Successful through the console]

---

I am able to create a CNAME record through the AWS console no problem see picture above. But when I try to do the same thing programmatically with the AWS Route53 SDK I keep getting an

> com.amazonaws.services.route53.model.InvalidInputException: Invalid
> request (Service: AmazonRoute53; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
> InvalidInput; Request ID: 7fd7b5d1-5ea8-11e8-a252-7f474094c446)

Here's my attempted code

```
    private static final String QA_HOSTED_ZONE_ID = "UUIDFromConsole";                

    GetHostedZoneRequest getHostedZoneRequest = new GetHostedZoneRequest(HOSTED_ZONE_ID);
        GetHostedZoneResult result = route53Client.getHostedZone(getHostedZoneRequest);
        ResourceRecordSet resourceRecordSet = new 
        ResourceRecordSet("DN4TheRecordSet", RRType.CNAME);
        GeoLocation geoLocation = new GeoLocation();
        geoLocation.setContinentCode("NA");
        geoLocation.setSubdivisionCode("NY");
        resourceRecordSet.setGeoLocation(geoLocation);
        resourceRecordSet.setTTL(50L);
        resourceRecordSet.setGeoLocation(geoLocation);
        resourceRecordSet.setSetIdentifier("uniqueid-statecode");Change addStateChange = new Change(ChangeAction.CREATE, resourceRecordSet);
        ChangeBatch changeBatch = new ChangeBatch(Arrays.asList(addStateChange));
        ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest changeResourceRecordSetsRequest = new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest().withHostedZoneId(HOSTED_ZONE_ID).withChangeBatch(changeBatch);
        route53Client.changeResourceRecordSets(changeResourceRecordSetsRequest);
```

I am also not able to configure the value for the CNAME, meaning where I want to redirect my traffic after it hits the `DN4TheRecordSet`.This is probably the cause of the invalid error I am receiving in the response.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

The [InvalidInputException](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/model/InvalidInputException.html) was eluding to the fact of a missing [ResourceRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/model/ResourceRecord.html) which corresponds to the value field in the picture above.

Here's the solution above with the addition of a [ResourceRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/model/ResourceRecord.html) to the [ResourceRecordSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/model/ResourceRecordSet.html)

```
private static final String QA_HOSTED_ZONE_ID = "UUIDFromConsole";                
private static final String REDIRECT_DNS = "DNS to want the cname to route to";
GetHostedZoneRequest getHostedZoneRequest = new GetHostedZoneRequest(HOSTED_ZONE_ID);
    GetHostedZoneResult result = route53Client.getHostedZone(getHostedZoneRequest); ResourceRecordSet resourceRecordSet = new ResourceRecordSet("DN4TheRecordSet", RRType.CNAME);
    GeoLocation geoLocation = new GeoLocation();
    geoLocation.setContinentCode("NA");
    geoLocation.setSubdivisionCode("NY");
    resourceRecordSet.setGeoLocation(geoLocation);
    resourceRecordSet.setTTL(50L);
    resourceRecordSet.setGeoLocation(geoLocation);
    resourceRecordSet.setSetIdentifier("uniqueid-statecode");
    resourceRecordSet.setResourceRecords(Arrays.asList(new ResourceRecord(REDIRECT_DNS))); // This line being missing cause the exception
    Change addStateChange = new Change(ChangeAction.CREATE, resourceRecordSet);
    ChangeBatch changeBatch = new ChangeBatch(Arrays.asList(addStateChange));
    ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest changeResourceRecordSetsRequest = new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest().withHostedZoneId(HOSTED_ZONE_ID).withChangeBatch(changeBatch);
    route53Client.changeResourceRecordSets(changeResourceRecordSetsRequest);
```

See Geolocation Syntax section in this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeResourceRecordSets.html#API_ChangeResourceRecordSets_Examples) for example of the payload the sdk creates and sends for your request.